# TSDocs on TypeScript String Literal Types

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm trying to figure out a way to have TSDocs work with a string literal type declaration in TypeScript.

For example:

```
type InputType = 
/** the TSDoc doesn't works for num1, but i'd like it to */
'num1' |
/** the TSDoc doesn't work for num2, but i'd also like it to */
'num2'

export const test = (...input: InputType[]) => {
    return input
}

tac('num1')
```

I'd like `'num1'` & `'num2` to show the TSDoc in VSCode or other tools with the comment, but the tools do not currently show the comment when typing in `'ma1'`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to document here?

Comment: @VLAZ, I have a few hundred different options for values to be inputted into `test` and I want to be able to give context on each of those possible inputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option you can do:

```js
  type InputType = "num1" | "num2";

  /**
   *
   * @param {"num1"} input description for num2
   */
  function test(...input: ["num2", ...string[]]): ["num2"];
  /**
   *
   * @param {"num1"} input description for num1
   */
  function test(...input: ["num1", ...string[]]): ["num1"];
  /**
   *
   * @param {string} input description for numX
   */
  function test(...input: [string, ...string[]]): ["numX"];
  function test<T extends InputType, R extends T[]>(...input: [...R]) {
    return input;
  }


  
  test("num4");
```

[image]

Comment: It is looks like you have a lot of writing )

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct that you want something like this:

```
/**
 * the TSDoc works for num1
 */
type A = 'num1';

/**
 * the TSDoc works for num2
 */
type B = 'num2';

export const test = (...input: (A | B)[]) => {
    return input
}

test('num1');
```

You can also check [the following TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhFgCgAIWgXAFgU2gFQMoBED2BjaAdxwCcBrAZ2gDNToA7AVwFsBGKWYKeATwAdUAQWgBeaAHImbcQG4oUUBBhwkqTLgLFyVWiQYsATBxBdIvAdABCoiVIOz5kZAA8+peNDw56FD-GS+NgAUAHRhAJb0fIzwAFzQQcIAPlYAlADaALqpogB80ADeHNAlJMjwjCT00JHR8FAAvo7+vkGSLKziqTJAA).

Comment: No, those comments don't carry across via tsdocs anywhere else.